# how to change the SVG color on hover in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, hover

I try to change the svg color when i hover the icon ,,,
first i just try to change the collor but it not work

```
import img1 from "../../../assets/specialities/specialities-01.svg";


< div className="rounded-lg w-40 border" >
        <div className="my-12">
          <figure className="bg-[#F2F6F6] p-4 rounded-full hover:bg-[#0E82FD] mx-auto w-[90px] h-[90px] grid justify-center items-center">
          <img src={img1} alt="" className="text-black fill-black" />
          </figure>
          <p className="text-center text-lg font-semibold">Cardiology</p>
        </div>
</div >
```

i try to change using text and fill but it not work ,,,,,,,,

my svg coHere's the source code for the SVG:

```
<svg width="36" height="51" viewBox="0 0 36 51" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M32.703 31.3594C32.5692 31.4844 32.4856 31.5602 32.4045 31.6399C31.1144 32.9165 29.6673 33.9377 27.968 34.556C25.3285 35.5174 22.6376 35.4522 19.9891 34.7595C17.2724 34.0481 14.5994 33.1465 11.9239 32.2742C9.73201 31.5588 7.66491 31.6586 5.81262 33.1638C4.28319 34.4058 3.43809 36.1464 2.78335 37.9893C2.73062 38.1383 2.81165 38.3776 2.89784 38.5345C3.88058 40.3203 5.08328 41.9346 6.48793 43.388C9.82591 46.8373 13.9292 48.8864 18.3747 50.2879C19.4115 50.6137 20.4984 50.7679 21.5622 51.0006H23.4917C23.6139 50.9687 23.7335 50.9222 23.8583 50.9049C25.4224 50.6868 26.7731 50.0246 27.878 48.8465C28.7514 47.9157 29.41 46.836 29.9014 45.6552C31.7459 41.2259 32.7042 36.5985 32.7441 31.7716C32.7454 31.6519 32.721 31.5322 32.703 31.3594ZM11.4698 43.7071C10.9977 43.7045 10.5823 43.267 10.59 42.7803C10.599 42.3016 10.9823 41.908 11.4518 41.8974C11.9483 41.8867 12.3445 42.2777 12.3497 42.7856C12.3548 43.2803 11.9458 43.7085 11.4698 43.7071ZM9.72043 40.0478C8.25532 40.0571 7.08864 38.8643 7.07835 37.3471C7.06806 35.8312 8.21159 34.6159 9.67413 34.5919C11.1367 34.568 12.3651 35.8206 12.3548 37.3232C12.3445 38.8324 11.1778 40.0384 9.72043 40.0478ZM14.1299 40.0637C14.1273 39.5597 14.5261 39.1435 15.0072 39.1475C15.4908 39.1502 15.8832 39.5704 15.8741 40.0757C15.8664 40.5863 15.4728 40.9692 14.9724 40.9546C14.4939 40.94 14.1312 40.557 14.1299 40.0637ZM15.8651 44.614C15.3828 44.602 14.9905 44.1739 15.0059 43.6765C15.0213 43.1939 15.4034 42.8122 15.8767 42.8096C16.3784 42.8056 16.7553 43.1939 16.7514 43.7125C16.7476 44.2217 16.3501 44.626 15.8651 44.614ZM19.4012 37.3338C19.89 37.3285 20.2952 37.738 20.2939 38.2353C20.2939 38.734 19.8887 39.1435 19.4012 39.1369C18.906 39.1316 18.533 38.7273 18.5445 38.2101C18.5561 37.7154 18.924 37.3378 19.4012 37.3338ZM19.3819 47.3373C18.8828 47.3213 18.5239 46.9171 18.5458 46.3958C18.5664 45.9118 18.9587 45.5235 19.4205 45.5288C19.8952 45.5355 20.3068 45.973 20.2952 46.4597C20.2836 46.957 19.8707 47.3532 19.3819 47.3373ZM19.3948 42.7949C18.9317 42.7843 18.5535 42.3867 18.5445 41.9014C18.5355 41.3868 18.915 40.9812 19.4076 40.9772C19.8874 40.9746 20.2991 41.3987 20.2952 41.8894C20.2901 42.3774 19.8643 42.8056 19.3948 42.7949ZM23.8261 37.3325C24.3201 37.3351 24.706 37.7447 24.6957 38.2526C24.6854 38.7632 24.2866 39.1529 23.7914 39.1369C23.3245 39.1209 22.945 38.722 22.9399 38.242C22.936 37.742 23.3373 37.3298 23.8261 37.3325ZM23.8531 48.2561C23.3721 48.2747 22.9514 47.8678 22.9399 47.3718C22.9283 46.8852 23.3399 46.4464 23.8133 46.441C24.2892 46.4344 24.7008 46.8612 24.6995 47.3572C24.697 47.8412 24.3226 48.2388 23.8531 48.2561ZM25.5845 45.5222C24.1297 45.5195 22.9424 44.3015 22.936 42.8043C22.9283 41.2977 24.1606 40.0305 25.6102 40.0544C27.0625 40.0783 28.2279 41.307 28.2253 42.8096C28.2215 44.3161 27.0458 45.5235 25.5845 45.5222ZM29.1219 39.1369C28.6344 39.1409 28.2305 38.73 28.233 38.2314C28.2343 37.7327 28.6395 37.3258 29.1283 37.3325C29.6235 37.3404 29.994 37.7447 29.9811 38.2633C29.9695 38.7566 29.5991 39.1329 29.1219 39.1369Z" fill="#0E82FD"/>
<path d="M32.1624 25.9376C31.5566 23.2449 30.6124 20.7011 28.9209 18.5151C28.1067 17.4646 27.1548 16.5923 25.8775 16.1641C25.1083 15.9048 24.4549 15.9461 23.885 16.6388C23.5081 17.0989 22.9743 17.0909 22.6052 16.7266C22.2398 16.3649 22.245 15.849 22.6309 15.3942C23.2727 14.6389 24.0973 14.1642 24.99 13.8065C26.6493 13.1443 28.373 13.0725 30.1172 13.26C30.7308 13.3252 31.3405 13.4369 31.9888 13.5326C31.8769 11.7282 32.4519 10.2097 33.5903 8.89988C27.1381 6.21119 20.466 8.27226 15.9009 14.1509C15.9356 14.1842 15.9678 14.2227 16.0064 14.2493C19.145 16.442 20.9754 19.5975 22.1691 23.217C22.38 23.8592 22.1768 24.3592 21.679 24.5374C21.1593 24.7222 20.713 24.4297 20.4969 23.7661C19.8229 21.7024 18.8697 19.7929 17.5268 18.1069C16.0064 16.1987 14.1489 14.8145 11.7191 14.514C7.12825 13.9448 3.11239 16.3689 1.31284 20.7703C-0.760697 25.8392 -0.17028 30.8602 1.62927 35.9942C1.79135 35.6605 1.88139 35.469 1.97529 35.2802C2.95546 33.3015 4.3331 31.6899 6.287 30.7405C8.32967 29.7485 10.4405 29.8336 12.5758 30.573C14.9786 31.404 17.3969 32.1992 19.8396 32.8867C21.899 33.4651 24.0137 33.6699 26.1387 33.2045C28.7859 32.626 30.7758 31.0104 32.4364 28.8935C32.5393 28.7632 32.5728 28.5212 32.5483 28.343C32.4403 27.5385 32.3412 26.7287 32.1624 25.9376ZM8.19718 18.4858C5.8085 19.4126 4.6521 21.3846 4.01538 23.7728C3.80828 24.5507 3.72724 25.3671 3.61148 26.1689C3.54973 26.5918 3.49442 26.9973 3.06351 27.2021C2.43321 27.504 1.7772 27.0146 1.81064 26.266C2.06662 23.4111 2.78952 20.7503 4.78331 18.6201C5.56667 17.7824 6.49153 17.1641 7.56431 16.8024C8.0724 16.6309 8.5522 16.8769 8.70784 17.3423C8.8622 17.8063 8.6744 18.301 8.19718 18.4858Z" fill="#0E82FD"/>
<path d="M14.0324 13.173C9.59982 11.8912 5.71645 12.8432 2.20996 15.9109C2.46851 15.2833 2.68976 14.6357 2.99204 14.032C3.45511 13.1052 4.08283 12.2808 4.92794 11.7143C6.67603 10.5442 7.46068 8.8009 7.75782 6.77973C7.91089 5.73457 7.90446 4.66415 7.96749 3.60569C7.97649 3.46209 7.96878 3.31715 7.96878 3.16423C11.7878 3.96472 11.7878 3.96472 14.9779 3.15625C15.122 6.55501 14.8763 9.90457 14.0324 13.173Z" fill="#0E82FD"/>
<path d="M14.9386 0.950785C14.069 2.1821 9.30966 2.33103 7.96289 0.980039C9.31223 -0.320425 13.7178 -0.323084 14.9386 0.950785Z" fill="#0E82FD"/>
<path d="M34.8134 13.8034C34.6346 13.9802 34.295 14.169 34.1162 14.1025C33.9348 14.0347 33.8435 13.6651 33.7483 13.4138C33.6994 13.2821 33.7251 13.1199 33.7148 12.9284C33.7843 11.9258 34.1097 10.983 34.8326 10.2384C35.0372 10.0283 35.3768 9.96047 35.6546 9.82617C35.7717 10.1054 35.9762 10.3807 35.9916 10.6666C36.0572 11.8846 35.6752 12.9563 34.8134 13.8034Z" fill="#0E82FD"/>
<path d="M26.4694 42.7758C26.4797 43.2625 26.0681 43.7 25.5947 43.7053C25.1149 43.7119 24.7162 43.2957 24.7188 42.7891C24.72 42.2891 25.0738 41.9115 25.5562 41.8969C26.0462 41.8822 26.4591 42.2785 26.4694 42.7758Z" fill="#0E82FD"/>
<path d="M10.5775 37.3406C10.5685 37.8486 10.1646 38.2488 9.67962 38.2302C9.19725 38.2116 8.81007 37.7781 8.83194 37.2808C8.8538 36.7981 9.2397 36.4231 9.71435 36.4258C10.216 36.4285 10.5865 36.8207 10.5775 37.3406Z" fill="#0E82FD"/>
</svg>
```

change the svg color when i hover the icon

Comment: img elements are not interactive so you'd need to provide two different images and swap between them or use a different element e.g. <object> that is interactive.